# How to expand Table Row border

Tags: css

currently I have borders around all my rows. I'm looking to style the borders so they grow past the table on the left and right by a couple pixels. At the moment they all remain within the table

I hard coded the border with the following styles

```
--outline-box-shadow-color: ${colorTheme.primary.base};
&:focus  {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2pt var(--outline-offset-box-shadow-color), 0 0 0.75pt 3.5pt var(--outline-box-shadow-color);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o0tev173/

Looking to have it extend a bit out like this on both left and right.

[image]

Any tips or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add a box shadow with a negative x value and no blur like so:

```css
#TR_8, #TR_18, #TR_28, #TR_38 {
    box-shadow: -6px 0 0 #369;
}
```

You can combine that with your current box-shadow value or use that by itself.

Comment: Hi, I tried what you suggested, unfortunately it wasn't outside of the table. Anychance can you tweak on fiddler?

Comment: @Master you might have your definition too high up and it could be overridden. I’ll tweak the fiddler

Comment: Thanks for the JS Fiddle, but unfortunately that resolves for one side. Top and bottom should remain as is, left and right should be extended outwards.